# Handling HTML Attr tags w/ CSS

Tags: html, css

is it possible to change the value of an HTML attribute w/ CSS? I know you can select elements by attr and add in content, but is it possible to actually change the value of the attribute itself? I know the answer is probably no, but after some searching and wondering I just wanted to make sure if this was possible or not.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Be more specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. The answer is  no. The purpose of CSS is presentation, and not semantics (the purpose of HTML).

Answer (score 0):

Nope. You need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. But it's possible with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You would need javascript to do this -- i am unaware of a way to change attribute tags with only CSS.

Answer (score 0):

There’s no standardized way of doing what you’re suggesting in CSS, although old IE versions (IE < 8) have something very similar called [*CSS expressions*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2008/10/16/ending-expressions.aspx) (also known as [*dynamic properties*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634.aspx)). Basically, it allows you to use JavaScript in CSS, and it’s absolutely horrible:

```
/* please don’t ever use this! */
div {
  /* Emulate max-width: */
  width: expression(document.body.clientWidth > 800 ? '800px': 'auto');
  /* Use a different background color every hour: */
  background: expression((new Date()).getHours() % 2 ? 'red' : 'blue');
}
```

You should just use JavaScript though.

Answer (score 0):

Prior to Firefox 4, it used to be possible to add attributes to elements using CSS. (Well, sort of.)